# error updating doctrine with composer may be a bug?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I am getting the following error when i try to update doctrine with composer

```
[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git via git, https protocols, aborting.

  - git://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
    error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied


  - https://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
    error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I am using this line for doctrine in my composer.json

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
```

Comment: `Permission denied` -> please look at your permissions

Comment: Obiously i know that, however i think the permission is on the doctrine side on github. Meaning that they don't allow me to pull the latest version from the git

Comment: The permission issue is with the `.git/config` file on your computer. What user are you using? What are the permission settings on this file?

Comment: i am using a user that i made (called admin) on a centos system running cpanel, running it as root seems to work however thats not really a solution :s and i cant find the .git/config

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the doctrine folder within vendor has correct permissions. For me removing the doctrine folder and running update again fixed the problem.

```
$ sudo rm -rf vendor/doctrine ; ./composer update
```